# Characteristics of semilinear PDE $xu_x+yu_y+xyu_z=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

**Remark:**
Initially, I have incorrectly copied over the problem. The edit below shows the correct one and how I checked that the function really does satisfy the "new" pde.

I have a pde of the following form

$$xu_{x}+yu_{y}+xyu_{z}=0$$

with the boundary condition $$u(x,y,0)=x^2+y^2.$$

I solved the pde with the method of characteristic and got the solution
$$u(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-2(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x})z.$$

However, the other part of this problem asks me to explain the following.

We know that $u$ is constant along characteristics and we know that $u(x,y,0)\geq0$ then why is $u(1,1,1)=-2$.

What I was thinking is that even though we know that $u$ is going to be constant on each characteristic the fact that $u(1,1,1)=-2$ means that no characteristic curve begging on $(x,y,0)$ will pass through the point $(1,1,1)$. Am I correct in thinking this is the answer or is there something else that I forgot about.

**EDIT:**
Just to check that the solution really does satisfy the pde:

$$x(2x-2\frac{z}{y}+2\frac{yz}{x^2})+y(2y-2\frac{z}{x}+2\frac{xz}{y^2})-2xy(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x})=$$
$$=x^2-\frac{xz}{y}+\frac{yz}{x}+y^2-\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y}-x^2-y^2=0$$ Which really does satisfy the equation.

Comment: a Westlife. Did you put your solution $u(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-2(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x})z$ into the PDE $xu_{x}+yu_{y}+zu_{z}=0$ and check if it's agree ? You will be surprised.

Comment: I apologize I made a mistake in copying over the pde. I have edited the post.

Comment: I agree with the new equation and with your result. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xu_x+yuy+xyu_z=0$$
Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{du}{0}\:$finite $\implies\:du=0$.
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$\frac{y}{x}=c_2$$
A third characteristic equation comes from
$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{ydx+xdy}{yx+xy}=\frac{dz}{xy}\quad\implies\quad \frac12 d(xy)=dz$
$$xy-2z=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form $c_1=F(c_2,c_3)$ is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\:,\:xy-2z\right)}$$
$F(X,Y)$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

CONDITION : $u(x,y,0)=x^2+y^2$
$$x^2+y^2=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\: , \: xy\right)$$
With $X=\frac{y}{x}$ and $Y=xy$ $\quad\implies\quad$ $x^2=\frac{Y}{X}$ and $y^2=XY$.
$$F(X,Y)=x^2+y^2=\frac{Y}{X}+XY$$
So the function $F(X,Y)$ is known now. We put it into the above geheral solution where $X=\frac{y}{x}$ and $Y=xy-2z$.
$$u=\frac{xy-2z}{\frac{y}{x}}+\frac{y}{x}(xy-2z)$$
$$u=x^2+y^2-2z\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \right)$$
This is exactly the result that you obtained.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am still confused about the second part of the problem. Namely explaining why $u(1,1,1)=-2$ if we know that $u$ is constant along characteristics.

Comment: What is the problem ? $u$ is constant along each characteristic. But it is not constant from one characteristic to another.

Comment: That's kinda what I am confused about. How do we know that no characteristic from the boundary $(z=0)$ goes through the point $(1,1,1)$? I'm guessing that it obviously can't because otherwise, it would be positive. However I cant see why it cant .

Comment: The characteristic lines are on the 3D surface $x^2+y^2-2z\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \right)=c_1$. In setting $z=0$ one select those located on the plane $z=0$ wich are circles $x^2+y^2=c_1>0$. So the characteristic lines outside the plane $z=0$ are ignored. The point $(1,1,1)$ is outside this plane.So the selected characteristic lines cannot go to this point. On the other hand  the characteristic lines starting from $(1,1,1) $ are located on the 3D surface which equation is :  $x^2+y^2-2z\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \right)=- 2$ which doesn(t intersect the plan $z=0$.  No contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach the second half of the problem is to repeat the method of characteristics, but restricting to the characteristic which starts at $(1,1,1)$. Then the characteristic ODEs

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{du}{0}=ds$$

yield the solution $$x(s) =y(s)= e^s,\quad z(s)=\frac12 (e^{2s}+1)$$
with $u$ constant along the characteristic. Note that $z(s)\geq 1/2$ for all $s$, so this characteristic can never reach the $z=0$ plane on which the initial condition is prescribed. So requiring that $u$ is positive on the $z=0$ plane does not mean that $u$ must be positive everywhere.

This does raise the question of what points $(x,y,z)$ are connected to the $z=0$ plane by characteristics. If we generalize to arbitrary initial $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ then the solution for $z(s)$ becomes $$z(s)  =\frac12 x_0 y_0(e^{2s}-1)+z_0$$ which is bounded below by $z(-\infty)=z_0-x_0y_0/2$. Hence for $z_0> x_0 y_0/2$ the characteristic does not reach the $z=0$ plane. For comparison, the solution obtained by the OP can be expressed as

$$u(x,y,z) = (x/y+y/x)(xy-2z)$$ which is indeed negative only if $z >xy/2$. (In the present case, $z>xy/2$ is a sufficient condition for $u<0$ rather than just a necessary one. This appears specific to the initial condition $u(x,y,0)=x^2+y^2$. For instance, if $u(x,y,0)=x^2+y^2+a$ for some $a>0$, I expect that there would exist some nonnegative values of $u(x,y,z)$ in the region $z>xy/2$.)